# Suggest button partially obscures input field

Tags: bug, design, tag-synonyms

On the [suggestion synonym page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/support/synonyms) the “suggest” button partially obscures input field:

> [image]

Chrome for iOS.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome under Windows 7 as well so not limited to mobile.

Comment: Well, this happens due to the input having width of 100% which somehow conflicts with the new grid layout SE now use as part of responsive design. Removing the 100% CSS rule make it look fine.

Comment: @Sonic see my comment please. It is not limited to mobile.

Comment: @Shadow Author said he was using Chrome for iOS; I hadn't seen the comments.

Comment: @Sonic rule of thumb is to test with other browsers/OS and if a bug happens only for mobile, then indeed such tag is required.